# How can I extract the volume from an MP3 or MP4?

Tags: software, volume

I'm looking for a software program that will take an MP3 or MP4 as input and produce as output a text file with peak or average volume for each second (or some interval of seconds or sub-seconds).

Essentially, I want to produce a volume graph, but need the raw volume numbers so I can align the sound volumes to other data.

Ideally, I would like a 'headless' script so I can automate the extraction from multiple, very long sound files.

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: what have you already tried? what is the purpose besides measuring volume on mp3/4 files? do you have a budget?

Comment: @ArnoudTraa I'm trying to validate actigraph data on sleep/wake time by overlaying sound recordings of snoring and movement (and luminosity).  I haven't tried anything yet, although I've done a fair amount of googling to find something with this functionality. This is just for me, but I could spend a few hundred dollars if need be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you don't mention which platform/OS you're running, I would suggest [loudness-scanner](https://github.com/jiixyj/loudness-scanner).

Something like :

```
loudness dump -m 0.1 *.mp3 > data.txt
```

should provide you with a text file containing raw data (momentary loudness every 0.1 second).

Comment: I'm so amazed someone actually already wrote a program to do this. Is nothing left undone in the world?

Comment: @audionuma This sounds like exactly what i want, but i'm having trouble getting it to build on OS X, which is my primary platform.  I could run it on Windows or get a Linux box on Amazon if it comes to that.  if i can get that sorted and run a successful test, I'll accept this as the answer

Comment: @audionuma I have not been able to get a build on OS X, but will accept this answer anyway since it appears to be sound. Like your r128x library, btw. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm suprised you didn't find this earlier...

http://projects.sappharad.com/mp3gain/

If you read through the webpage it seems obvious that there is a scriptable option available as well. Can't test it as I don't have a Mac OS X test machine available currently though.

http://projects.sappharad.com/mp3gain/aacgain_19_mac_cmdline.zip

Comment: It is a nice program, but it doesn't provide the momentary gain data as an output, it only adjusts the gain on the file or files as a whole.